# How to show that $\sigma^\mu_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}} \bar\sigma_\mu^{\dot{\beta} \beta} = 2\delta_\alpha ^\beta \delta_\dot{\alpha}^\dot\beta$?

Tags: representation-theory, spinors, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

Consider the usual definitions $\sigma^\mu = (1, \sigma^i)$ and $\bar\sigma^\mu = (1, -\sigma^i)$, is it possible to show

$$\sigma^\mu_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}} \bar\sigma_\mu^{\dot{\beta} \beta} = 2\delta_\alpha ^\beta \delta_\dot{\alpha}^\dot\beta$$

without resorting to going through each index manually?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/249502/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/200800/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/293396/2451 and links therein.

Comment: RHS should be contain the epsilon spinors ${\epsilon_{\alpha}}^{\beta}$